# Bash declare/init variables from array using a reference

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The following code snippet will try to initialize the variables in the `arrVAR_INIT` array :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

declare -a arrVAR_INIT=(
    VERBOSE=FALSE
    DEBUG=FALSE
    MEMORY="1024k"
    DEBUGFILE=
)

# declare -A arrVAR_DEFAULT_VALUE

for VAR in "${arrVAR_INIT[@]}"
do
    VAR_NAME=${VAR%%=*}
    VAR_VALUE="${VAR#*=}"
    echo "$VAR : $VAR_NAME = \"$VAR_VALUE\""

    #### ERROR: !VAR_NAME: unbound variable
    declare $VAR_NAME="$VAR_VALUE"

    # eval "arrVAR_DEFAULT_VALUE[${VAR%%=*}]=\"${VAR#*=}\""

done
```

Please note that, by using the `set -u` ( treat unset variables as an error, and immediately exit ), the above code will throw the *!VAR_NAME: unbound variable* error and exit.

What would be the correct way to init the vars though the reference ?

Can it be done without using `eval` ?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is :

```
declare "$VAR_NAME=$VAR_VALUE"
```

Know that if you cannot guarantee the content of the variables is safe, this could open code injection vulnerabilities.

Is there a reason you are not using an associative array?  You already have an array to start with, why not make it associative and read from it rather than initializing other variables?

```
declare -A arrVAR_INIT=(
    [VERBOSE]=FALSE
    [DEBUG]=FALSE
    [MEMORY]="1024k"
    [DEBUGFILE]=
)

echo "${arrVAR_INIT[VERBOSE]}" # An example of getting a value out of the array.
```

Comment: This is funny as I am building the associative array which will be later used to check iif the mandatory variables have been reassigned !
`declare -A arrVAR_DEFAULT_VALUE ;
    for VAR in "${arrVAR_INIT[@]}" ; do
        local VAR_NAME=${VAR%%=*} ;
        local VAR_VALUE=${VAR#*=} ; 
        declare $VAR_NAME="$VAR_VALUE" ;
        eval "arrVAR_DEFAULT_VALUE[${VAR%%=*}]=\"${VAR#*=}\"" ;
    done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `declare $var_name="$var_value"` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u

declare -a arrvar_init=(
    VERBOSE=FALSE
    DEBUG=FALSE
    MEMORY="1024k"
    DEBUGFILE=
)

# declare -A arrVAR_DEFAULT_VALUE

for var in "${arrvar_init[@]}"
do
    var_name=${var%%=*}
    var_value=${var#*=}

    declare $var_name="$var_value"

    declare -p $var_name
done
```

Avoid using all uppercase names for your variable names to avoid clash with bash ENV variables.